# Preimage of the set of $x$-values

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> What is the preimage of the set of $x$-values between $0$ and $1$?
>   i.e. $f^{−1}(\{x\mid 0<x<1\})$? Explain.

I get that we have to find the inverse image
$f^{-1}(S) = \{a\in A \mid f(a) \in S\}$ where $S$ is the set of $x$-values between (but not including) $0$ and $1$. I do not know how to explain this and this is where it is giving me problems.

Comment: What do you mean with -1 ({|0 < < 1}?

Comment: inverse function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ f^{-1}(\{ x :0 <x <1\})=f^{-1}((0,1))$

which is the set of values of $\mathbb {R}$ such that $ f $ evaluated in any of the elements of the set falls in the interval $( 0,1) $ written formally,

$ f^{-1}((0,1))=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f (x)\in (0,1)\}$

Im assuming $ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb {R}$

Answer (score 0):

If we denote $x=f(y)$, you have to find all the $y$ values such that $0<f(y)<1$, which is by definition $f^{-1}(]0,1[)$.

Comment: Could you explain the $]0,1[$ notation?

Comment: @mapierce271 It's the open interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: It means all the values between 0 (excluded) and 1 excluded. Maybe you're used to the notation (0,1).